# What is the point of having open class with private constructor?

Tags: kotlin

I have code like this:

```kotlin
open class A private constructor()
```

As it looks to me having the class `open` does not make sense since when constructing a child I would not be able to construct a part of a base class.

However neither compiler nor IDE even warns me about I'm using inefficient syntax. Which makes me believe I'm missing some knowledge here..

So what is the point of coupling `open` with a private constructor in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that on its own it would make no sense to have an open class with a private constructor.

But it could be a stepping stone to something that does if you add a secondary constructor, eg:

```
open class A private constructor(private val prop: String) {
   
    constructor() : this("someVal")

}

class B : A()
```

This might be useful if you want to keep knowledge of what to provide as the primary constructor's parameter in the parent class.

Or, if the primary constructor remains without parameters, perhaps you use a secondary constructor which acts as a check to ensure the constructor of a child object holds some kind of token (perhaps to control when an object can be constructed), eg:

```
open class A private constructor() {
   
    constructor(token: Token) : this()

}

class B(token: Token) : A(token)

interface Token
```

Just some ideas. You can probably think of some more.

Answer (score 0):

So it has no exact use case. But as the "type" of an open class still is a normal class you can use it their too. I dont see why kotlin should disallow to use a private constructor their

Comment: I am not talking about disallowing private constructor but rather about disallowing `open` modifier with private constructor